# Various selects in form controlled by one main select

Tags: javascript, html

I want to update my dropdowns based on the main dropdown menu via javascript.

Consider this: there is a main select menu (dropdown) with months, from january to december, and we have 3 other blocks, but in those blocks there is month select, but, in this case they should be selected with the same month that was selected in the main selection. I don't know if I'm clear. **If I change the main select, it should be reflected on the other 3.**

I don't understand how to begin, because I can put some "onChange" event in the main select to call a javascript function, but I don't know how this javascript code can change the values of the other 3 selects of years in the other 3 blocks of the webpage.

I'm writing from my cellphone because I'm in a train so sadly I don't have any code to share with you, because I just only could make work the "OnChange" event.

Please suggest some solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct start. 
By listening the changes from the Main selection, get the corresponding field from data to create new options for the child selection.
Here is an example. Hope can help.

```js
let data ={
  opt1 : { 
    child1 : ["opt1-child1-1","opt1-child1-2"],
    child2 : ["opt1-child2-1","opt1-child1-2"],
    child3 : ["opt1-child3-1","opt1-child1-2"],
  },
  opt2 : { 
    child1 : ["opt2-child1-1","opt2-child1-2"],
    child2 : ["opt2-child2-1","opt2-child1-2"],
    child3 : ["opt2-child3-1","opt2-child1-2"],
  }
};
$("#main").on('change',function(){
  let main = $(this).val();
  console.log(main);
  
  //set child1
  $("#child1").html(""); //clean
  data[main].child1.forEach(ele => {
    $("#child1").append(`<option value="${ele}">${ele}</option>`);
  });
    //set child2
     $("#child2").html(""); //clean
  data[main].child2.forEach(ele => {
    $("#child2").append(`<option value="${ele}">${ele}</option>`);
  });
  //set child3
   $("#child3").html(""); //clean
  data[main].child3.forEach(ele => {
    $("#child3").append(`<option value="${ele}">${ele}</option>`);
  });
      
});
```

```html
<div>
<select id="main">
<option disabled selected>---Pick one---</option>
  <option value="opt1">opt1</option>
  <option value="opt2">opt2</option>
</select>
</div>
<select id="child1">
  <option disabled selected>---choose main first---</option>
</select>

<select id="child2">
  <option disabled selected>---choose main first---</option>
</select>

<select id="child3">
  <option disabled selected>---choose main first---</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```